# Differentiability of the following function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Prove that the following function's differential is nonsigular at the origin:

Define $F = (f,g):\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ by $f(x,y) = x$, and 
$ g(x,y) = y-x^2$ for $y \ge x^2$, $ g(x,y) = y(y-x^2)/x^2$ for $0 \le y \lt x^2$, $ g(x,y) = -y(y+x^2)/x^2$ for $-x^2 \le y \lt 0$ and $ g(x,y) = y+x^2$ for $ y \lt -x^2$.

I cannot seem to see how the differential is nonsingular when some partial derivatives don't even exist at the origin. For example, $g_y = (y-x^2)/x^2 + y/x^2$ for $0 \le y \lt x^2$ which does not exist when $x = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $g_y(0,0) = 1.$ You can see this by noting $g(0,y) = y$ for all $y.$

In fact, $F(x,0) = (x,0)$ for all $x,$ $F(0,y)= (0,y)$ for all $y.$ Thus the matrix of partial derivatives for $F$ at $(0,0)$ is just the identy matrix, which of course is nonsingular.

There is still work to do: Is $F$ differentiable at $(0,0)?$ I'll leave that to you for now.